# How to configure fetchPolicy to network-only

Tags: apollo-client

How can I set the `fetchPolicy` to `network-only` in `apollo-client`? I can't understand how to do it!

Comment: It depends a bit on how you're using apollo-client, but if you look at the docs: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.query you can replace the `forceFetch` option with `fetchPolicy`.

If you have some code to share, likely someone could provide more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass it as a query option. [Docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.query)

```
graphql(searchQuery, { 
    options: ({props}) => ({
        variables: {
            UserID: props.userID,
            Phone: props.phone,
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

ran into the same issue, but an upgrade to `apollo-client@1.0.0-rc.9` and `react-apollo@1.0.0-rc.3` seems to have solved it: the connected component now refetches its query every time it's rendered. Try upgrading.

(Can't comment, so posting this as an "answer". Sorry about that.)

Comment: I did the same thing! They seem to have solved it. Sorry didn't get time to edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it without using `fetchPolicy`. It's sort of a hack. In my GraphQL query, I pass a random value each time it's executed. Like this:

```
graphql(searchQuery, {
    options: ({props}) => ({
        variables: {
            UserID: props.userID,
            Phone: props.phone,
            Dicard: new Date().getTime().toString()
        }
    })
})
```

I will accept my answer till I find a solution. I also opened an issue on GitHub. Turns out many others are also facing the same issue!

**EDIT**: when updating to `apollo-client@1.0.0-rc.9` and `react-apollo@1.0.0-rc.3`, `fetchPolicy` works nicely!